# Append json file with array using php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

i have json file with array and i want to add array elemnts to that array using php . please advice me to proceed.

here is my existing json file

## data.json

```
{
"12":{"userId":"1","username":"Ss","password":"33"},
"32":{"userId":"1","username":"Ss","password":"33"}
}
```

## my php file

below is my code part which i need to append with my existing json file.

```
$data[$thisId] = array( 
    'userId'=> $userId, 
    'username'=> $username,
        'password'=> $password, 
          ); 
$json = json_encode($data);
```

how can i add this to my json file ? pls advice

: I want to write the data which come from php file into my existing json file

Comment: There is no array in your JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to decode your file to append your datas :

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'), true);
$data[$thisId] = array( 
    'userId'=> $userId, 
    'username'=> $username,
    'password'=> $password, 
); 
$json = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('data.json', $json);
```

Comment: what i want is to write the content of my php file ($json) in to my data.json file . pls advice

Comment: You can use `file_put_contents` function to write your data.json file. You can see my updated answer ;-)

Comment: you code works , but it removes existing json part and keep only the latest . how can i keep all

Comment: Can you try with `json_decode('data.json', true);` please ?

Comment: Glad to help you ;-)

Comment: can you check this one too please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837591/is-it-possible-to-update-js-file-using-php-command