# Is it possible to update js file using php command?

Tags: javascript, php

I have script.js file. and it has following array

## script.js

```
  'COntent': function() {

            var contentFacts = {

                blocks: {

                    'block1': {

                        name: 'yleow',

                        title: 'H2',

                        type: 'content'

                    }

                }

            };

        }

    },
```

I tried like this in my php , but it did not work :(

```
$lines = file($path.'/script.js');
$lines[64] = "'block2': {name: 'yleow',title: 'H2',type: 'content'}"

file_put_contents($path.'/script.js', implode($lines));
```

I want to add another element call block2 for this array. How can i update my script.js file function using php?
Is it possible using file_put_contents? please advice

Comment: My advice: don't.

Comment: @AlexPánek : please explain? isn't it possible ?

Comment: Why not have your array in a txt file with that array as JSON, then include that file in your JS function and parse it?  You can use PHP to update the JSON in the file.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a *very* poor substitute for a database or any other structured data format. In this case even more because you are trying to inject content into *source code*.

What you probably want is some form of structured data outside of your code for example a JSON file or an SQLite database.

PHP does support parsing from and serializing to JSON:

- [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)
- [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

---

### Possible solution

Put the `contentFacts` into a seperate JSON file

```
{
  "blocks": {
    "block1": {
      name: 'yleow',
      title: 'H2',
      type: 'content'
    }
  }
}
```

Manipulate JSON with PHP

```
$json = file($path.'/blocks.json');

$blocks = json_decode($json, true);

$blocks['block2'] = array(
  'name'  => 'blue',
  'title' => 'h3',
  'type'  => 'content'
);
```

Write back to JSON file

```
$adapted_json = json_encode($blocks);

file_put_contents($path.'/blocks.json');
```

Now you need to get this into your JavaScript part, I assume on the client. You can do this by requesting it from the server:

```
const contentPromise = fetch('/path/to/blocks.json');

contentPromise.then((blocks) => {
  // Do something with those blocks. (render them to the page?)
});
```